# Again |Access is denied| after trying to get running process properties

Tags: c#

```
string FILE = process.MainModule.Filename;    
var fs = File.GetAccessControl(FILE);    
var sid = fs.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
Console.WriteLine(sid); // SID

var ntAccount = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
Console.WriteLine(ntAccount);
```

I can't use this code for running processes as shown in Task manager. I am using XP. The exception is |Access is denied|.  Also, I like to know how to get the string LOCAL SERVICE, NETWORK SERVICE and SYSTEM as in the Task Manager. Thank you

Comment: Which line gives the Access denied error?

Answer (score 0):

[File.GetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getaccesscontrol.aspx) will throw an access is denied exception if the file is read-only or you do not have the required permissions.